# Absolutely positioned elements in responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm not sure this is possible, but I figured I'd see if someone had an idea for it.
I have a website that has a big fullscreen image as the main background.

Part of the image on the far right of the screen are some storm clouds. I would like to add in a lightning strike animation over the storm cloud area.

I can handle the css3 animation to create the lightning flash, but the issue is absolutely positioning the div(s) that will hold the images/animation to create the effect.  I need to position the div(s) right over the storm cloud area. (easy enough with: positioning the div at "right:0;bottom:40px")   As soon as you shrink the browser, obviously the background image size changes, and then the absolutely positioned div(s) are now not in the right area they should be.

Is there some way that Javascript can do this?

I was reading some on Css regions, but they are very experimental still, plus I'm not sure it would even work for my situation.

Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry to be confusing. I'm actually asking about keeping the divs over top of the storm cloud area only.  I only added the part about displaying these divs at certain widths just to let you know I'm not attempting this for very small layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use `media queries` directly in CSS for instance to hide your divs. A lot of explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

but an example would be:

```
<style>
 @media (max-width: 1024px) {
   .your-stuff {
     display: none;
   }
 }
</style>
```

Comment: I was actually asking about keeping the divs in a certain area of the screen when you shrink the browser. Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the lightning when the screen is less then 1024px resolution, you can remove it using a CSS media query.

Paste this in your CSS file and update the `.lightning` class to what ever your selector is.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .lightning { display: none; }
}
```

Learn more about media queries here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Sorry, my question seemed to be asking how to hide this for smaller widths, but that wasn't it. Thanks for your reply though!